# Input text is not visible in iphone safari and chrome browser

Tags: html, css, iphone, google-chrome, safari

[In this, breaktime label have input field, while I typed in this input field, It is not visible in iphone.[All input field in this project]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSTz8.png)

when I type in the input field, it is not visible in iphone browsers like chrome,safari,firefox but it is working fine in android browers.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know exactly why, but it's something wrong with a font-family. If I add a font-family explicitly to these inputs or to their container, like:

```
.timegroup {
  font-family: Arial; //or Helvetica, or whatever
}
```

it works on iphone browsers.

Comment: Can confirm this fix works on Chrome on Desktop Mac. Can't explain why either. The problem was only occurring intermittently, maybe less than 1 in 10 page refreshes, making it harder to debug.

Comment: Thanks Natalia. Awesome.. It's font-family Issue.

Comment: Natalia how you fix this issue? Have you faced this issue before?

Comment: @FasithA no, I haven't =) I've thought that there aren't too much reasons for text to be invisible and all of them are related with font styles: text color, font-size, font-family. So I've tried to play around with all these 3 parameters, and changing font-family helps!

Comment: @Natalia.. Good move.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add in your CSS the `transform` attribute to the `input`:

```css
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happen in iphone because of Font-family:Gotham.
You can change the font-family for input field and it will work fine in iphone browsers.